# grabbing exit code of background process/subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, subshell

I am wondering if there is any difference between:

```
long_running.sh & 
pid=$!
```

and

```
(
  long_running.sh
) & 

pid=$!
```

will the pid be capture consistently in both cases, or will there be some differences here?

ultimately, I want to capture the meaningful exit code with:

```
wait ${pid} || { echo "damn"; exit 1; };
```

Comment: not exactly. The first one is the PID of the shell running the long_running.sh script. The second one is the shell that is a subshell of your current shell: The shell running the script will be a child of the subshell.

Comment: thanks, I added more info to the question, ultimately I just need to get a meaningful exit code using `wait`

Answer (score 1):

A little testing shows my earlier comment is wrong:

```
$ cat long_running.sh 
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3
echo "long_running: $$"
pstree -ps $$
status=$((RANDOM % 2))
echo "exiting with status $status"
exit $status

$ ./long_running.sh
long_running: 6599
systemd(1)───gnome-terminal-(4112)───bash(5899)───long_running.sh(6599)───pstree(6601)
exiting with status 1

$ ( ./long_running.sh )
long_running: 6618
systemd(1)───gnome-terminal-(4112)───bash(5899)───long_running.sh(6618)───pstree(6621)
exiting with status 0
```

There's no "man-in-the-middle" shell, so I suppose bash spawns a subshell and `exec`s the commands.

To capture the exit status, you do the correct thing

```
$ ( ./long_running.sh ) & pid=$!; wait $pid && echo ok || echo damn
[1] 7439
long_running: 7439
systemd(1)───gnome-terminal-(4112)───bash(5899)───long_running.sh(7439)───pstree(7441)
exiting with status 0
[1]+  Done                    ( ./long_running.sh )
ok

$ ( ./long_running.sh ) & pid=$!; wait $pid && echo ok || echo damn
[1] 7457
long_running: 7457
systemd(1)───gnome-terminal-(4112)───bash(5899)───long_running.sh(7457)───pstree(7461)
exiting with status 1
[1]+  Exit 1                  ( ./long_running.sh )
damn
```

Comment: upvoted, can you add the conclusion of this using plain English, thanks!